# phpunit / Symfony: BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to test the http status code of URLs from my project.

By some tests I got the following error message from phpunit:

```
1) pp\TheBundle\Tests\UrlTests\UrlTests::test18Url
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'A Crawler cannot be serialized.' in /var/www/viasenso/muttersystem/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php:315
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->serialize()
#1 -(364): serialize(Array)
#2 -(513): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/viasenso/muttersystem/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php on line 315

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'A Crawler cannot be serialized.' in /var/www/viasenso/muttersystem/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php on line 315

BadMethodCallException: A Crawler cannot be serialized. in /var/www/viasenso/muttersystem/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.php on line 315

Call Stack:
    0.0022     441400   1. {main}() -:0
    0.0400    4434840   2. __phpunit_run_isolated_test() -:513
    0.6232   30949432   3. serialize() -:364
    0.6235   31024280   4. Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler->serialize() -:364
```

This is the content of the test function:

```
$crawler = $this->helper->getCrawler('/de/profil/the-profile/123/veroeffentlichen', [
    'user' => $this->helper->getParameter('testing')['user']['admin']['username'],
    'pwd' => $this->helper->getParameter('testing')['user']['admin']['password'],
]);


$this->assertEquals(Response::HTTP_OK, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(),
    'Status-Code ' . $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() . ' on URL ' . $this->client->getRequest()->getUri() . '');
```

Any ideas, why this error happens? The debugging informations from phpunit are not really helpfull...

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange solution, but it worked in my problem. Please, change assertEquals to assertContains.

Comment: This would fit better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Change config *processIsolation* to *false*, you should get a more clear test failed message